# CRM Error with Processes/Workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We're seeing an issue with our development CRM environment that we can't fix.

To recreate, I can make a new Process (Workflow) on any entity, e.g. Opportunity. I then put in a filter on a field which allows multiple values, e.g. Status Reason and pick 2 or more items (e.g. Won / In Progress). When pressing Save/Close, it gives an error message

"This process cannot be created, updated, or activated because it was created outside the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web application. Your organization does not allow this type of process."

The error details file has the following info:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: This workflow cannot be created, updated or published because it was created outside the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web application. Your organization does not allow this type of workflow.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147200960</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>This workflow cannot be created, updated or published because it was created outside the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web application. Your organization does not allow this type of workflow.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2018-06-05T11:49:06.9917786Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

If I try opening an existing workflow which has criteria where more than one value is used in an Equals statement, I get the following error:

```
Error generating UiData

[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadEvaluateCondition(EvaluateCondition activity)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadExpression(Collection`1 activities, Type endActivityType, Boolean customActivity, Int32&amp; activityIndex)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadBranchStep(StepBase parentStep, Collection`1 sequenceActivities, Int32&amp; activityIndex)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadConditionStep(Boolean wait, ConditionSequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadCompositeStep(String stepId, String description, Activity activity, Collection`1 variables)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.ReadSingleStep(Activity activity)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.GenerateUIData()

[CrmException: Error generating UiData]
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.UIDataGenerator.GenerateUIData()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.WorkflowLibrary.WorkflowAdapter.CreateWorkflowObjectModel(Guid workflowEntityId, Boolean useSystemUserContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Web.Sfa.WorkflowDetailPage.GetWorkflowStep()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Web.Sfa.WorkflowDetailPage.ConfigureForm()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
```

We've tried rebooting the server, restarting IIS, restarting the 5 CRM services running on the server, all to no avail.

I can change the operator to "Not Equal" and pick more than one item without any issue. The problem only happens when the operator is set to Equals and more than one item is picked.

This applies to every org on the server, including a Vanilla install which has no customisations. Whatever is doing this seems to be server-side

Have spent a while looking for anything on this but struggling.

Comment: Are you in CRM 2011? I remember some issues like this before moving to the latest RU (18)...

Comment: Yep, we are and are on RU18.

Comment: We've now "fixed" it - restarting the DB server seemed to do the job. Frustrating but good still